# My text-align:justify doesnt work

Tags: css, flexbox, text-align

I have a div that is child to one parent. text-align:justify doesnt work on it.

**Child HTML:**

```
<div id="right-text">По легенде, у расположенного на центральном острове<br> 
 Ворсменского озера Свято-Троицком монастыре были 
 большие<br> связи с  купечеством и представителями Италии.</div>
```

**Child CSS:**

```
#right-text {
width: 800px;
height: 400px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: justify;
}
```

**Parent CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color:#fff5e5;}
```

And what I get:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the `<br>` tags in order for the text justification to work. Then you can add a margin or width on the block of text.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark this answer as the correct answer :)